# Is there no perpetually free Azure subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, nodemailer

So I'm wanting to send emails from a Microsoft account using OAuth2 and everything I am reading says I need to setup some things in Azure Active Directory (for app registration to get a client secret and all this stuff) which I can do when I follow their instructions but everything seems to be contingent on an active Azure subscription which seems to cost a heck of a lot of dollars and cents.

I can create an account for free but that's only for up to a year. So am I wrong in thinking I won't be able to do this unless I pay heaven-knows-what for an Azure subscription?

*I'm going by these instructions*:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth

Comment: If you're using OAuth2, you must already have some kind of security exposure to AAD?

Comment: Not that I know of. I'm just using OAuth2 because Microsoft said they were going to end basic authentication for SMTP and so forth.

Comment: You can create an Azure Subscription and as long as you don't create and use any resources (Azure Subscription related) in it, you will not pay anything.

Comment: Also, I don't think you would need an Azure Subscription to access/manage Azure AD. When you login into Azure Portal it will complain about no subscriptions but you can ignore that and simply go to Azure AD to manage your Azure AD applications.

Comment: Thanks. I will check that out.

Comment: No subscription is required just for setting up the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to register the application in Azure AD to obtain the client secret  and other basic settings about the application, you do not need to subscribe.

Comment: I am happy of this if it is true. Thank you very much.